# Clock Domain Crossing: Is it possible to design an architecture from faster to slower domain and slower to faster domain simultaneously?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, vlsi, rtl

If I have a design which has read clock and write clock, and I want to make it work for the following scenarios:

1. faster read clock and slower write clock
2. slower read clock and faster write clock

Is this possible without changing the architecture from one scenario to other?

For example: I have a single pulse passing from one clock domain to another. I want it to be detected in either of the scenarios.

PS: Never worked on CDC before. Just started looking into it.

Comment: You don't specify whether you are using a FPGA or any other target. Since clock domain crossing can create subtle bugs, manyfacturers usually provide canned IP which does the job right. For example, you can use a small asynchronous FIFO core.

Comment: What needs to happen on the various kinds of clock edges, what kinds of handshaking delays are acceptable, and will anything be known "in advance" about changes in the clocks?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, it depends on the architecture of your design. For example, consider streaming 'data' and 'dataValid' from one domain to another.

If the source circuit clock is slower than the destination circuit clock, the dest' circuit can, and will, see 'dataValid' as asserted for more clocks than the source meant it to be. If the source clock is faster than the dest' clock, the dest' circuit can miss 'dataValid' being high altogether or see it as asserted for fewer clocks than the source meant it to be.

The list of concern areas goes on but the point is that the circuit must be designed with dataflow, travel times and handshaking between the two circuits in mind. It's often essential to plan it in from the start but sometimes can be added later with fewer problems. Then there's all the problems of designing out metastability.

It can all be done, all be done perfectly well, but it needs understanding and planning. It's not a trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one method is to insert "bubbles" (idle cycle) into whichever side is faster to keep the total # of cycles the same between both sides.  This is sort of a pseudo-synchronization technique for FIFO's.

Typically this would only be done on the faster side.  If the clocks can change which is faster, than you could put one on either side and disable whichever one is on the slower side.

Or you could go with an asynchronous FIFO solution which does not require anything special for slower/faster side.  To deal with metastability usually two FF's are used to store the write pointer (greatly reduces chance of metastability to a statistically negligible level), which gives a extra cycle of lag between read/write.  This increases the latency but has no effect on the throughput.

Comment: I am not clear on the first method. Can you please explain it more? Never came across this method. Thanks.

Comment: @ssgr: Suppose you have a clock ratio of 3:4.  Over a period of time the slower side will have 3 cycles while the faster side will have four cycles.  So if every 4th cycle on the fast side you disable everything (stall) for a cycle, then you will have an equal number of cycles on both sides.  The logic controller which accomplishes this is called a "bubble generator". https://www.google.com/patents/US8205111

Comment: A more generic term for what the"bubble generator" is doing is"flow control". Flow control can take many forms, but the basic idea is that there is some kind of two-way handshake between a producer and a consumer of information that prevents the slower side from being overwhelmed by the faster side. Even if the "information" is just a stream of pulses, there will be feedback that a pulse has been generated on the output side, so that another one can be accepted on the input side.

Comment: @DaveTweed: But, if you read the paper, the bubble generator is not part of the handshaking circuit (which is done with request/acknowledge logic) but rather is set by the ratios of clocks and uses dead reckoning to skip certain cycles.  As I said, this is just one method.

Comment: But you're assuming that one clock is directly derived from the other, so that they have a fixed and simple frequency relationship. The OP's question is more general than that, and in general, you need to assume that they're effectively asynchronous and uncontrolled, which is what drives the need for feedback.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Did you even read my answer or are you just prattling off? You mis-summarized the example paper I referenced, then when corrected chose some other non-issue to nitpick about.  As I said in the second paragraph "Or you could go with an asynchronous FIFO solution". Honestly you comment on a lot of my answers and it generally never adds anything to it except to inject yourself.